# Macbook Pro M1pro display process launching log when system restart

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, launchd, apple-silicon

[image]

I just killed process `launchd` carelessly with `Process Viewer` Application. As soon screen is black and restart.So when I restart my macbook ,it likes the image which displayed all process launching log.How do I make it invisible plz.. THANKS!!!

Comment: Does the Mac still boot normally allowing you to log in, or is it stuck somewhere? If it seems stuck, can you still boot into Recovery?

Comment: yes, it's still boot normally without stuck and it can boot into Recovery